# C# - Placing the characters of a text file into a 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, char, text-files

I want to take the contents of a text file and place it into a 2D array, character by character. I have included an example below

Text File

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMOP
```

2D Array (Char Array)

```
[
 [A,B,C,D,E]
 [F,G,H,I,J]
 [K,L,M,O,P]
]
```

What would be the best way of going about this? For the time being I am assuming that the length of the text file is also the width (in Char), I will fix it up later!

```
OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
string sFileName = openFile1.FileName;

int lineCount = File.ReadLines(sFileName).Count();

char[,] letters = new char[lineCount,lineCount];
```

Comment: Read the accepted answer on [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614694/how-to-convert-jagged-array-to-2d-array) I believe it answers your question exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [File.ReadLines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line) and then [String.ToCharArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(sFileName))
{
   lines.Append(line);
}
char[] char_array = lines.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

**EDIT:** When needing 2D array line by line;

```
List<char[]> lines = new List<char[]>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(sFileName))
{
   lines.Append(line.ToCharArray());
}
char[] char_array = lines.ToArray();
```

Comment: What should `lines.ToString()` do?

Comment: @joe this is the concatenated string from the StringBuilder but is irrelevant for an array of lines with each line a char array. (oops I now see you mean with the edit - just bad cut-n-paste!)

Comment: @Zohar missed that looking at the example but updated now

Comment: @Zohar yes thanks :o) only when I saw your edit did I realise I was a bit too quick off the mark!

Comment: this creates a jagged array (char[][]), not a multidimensional array (char[,]).

Comment: btw, I think your second attempt will create a jagged array, and not a 2d arrray. However, a jagged array is better suited for storing lines from a file, since there is no guarantee that the lines will all have the same number of characters...